# Split a string after reading square brackets in c#

Tags: c#

```
string test = "Account.Parameters[\"AccountNumber\"].Caption";
string new = test.Trim("[");
```

I want output `"AccoutNumber"`.
I have tried the below code but not getting the desired result:

```
string[] test = "Transaction.Parameters[\"ExpOtherX\"].Caption".Split('[');
string newvalue = test[1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Split` with two delimiters:

```
string[] test = "Transaction.Parameters[\"ExpOtherX\"].Caption".Split('[', ']');
string newvalue = test[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Regex:

```
string test = "Account.Parameters[\"AccountNumber\"].Caption";
var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(test, ".*?\\.Parameters\\[\"(.*?)\"]");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

`.*?` is a non greedy wildcart capture, so it will match your string until it reaches the next part (in our case, it will stop at `.Parameters["`, match the string, and then at `"]`)

It will match *.Parameters["..."].*, and extract the "..." part.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a Split to that string...

```
string test = "Account.Parameters[\"AccountNumber\"].Caption";
string output = test.Split('[', ']')[1];
Console.WriteLine(output);
```